# Erro com função PHP

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

Olá, estou desenvolvendo este sistema para fins de estudo e sempre que tento fazer alguma operação como cadastrar, editar ou excluir eu recebo a mensagem de erro: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function usuario_logado() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/estudandophp/menu_administrador.php on line 28" porém a operação é concluída. Pelo que pesquisei é como se a classe onde a função está definida não existisse mas acho que não é o caso. O que estou fazendo de errado? Abaixo as telas para dar uma noção do que estou fazendo:

Segue o código fonte da aplicação: [GitHub](https://github.com/guilherme-ramalho/estudandophp)

Comment: No arquivo menu_administrador.php voce esta chamando `usuario_logado()` mas em nenhum momento do arquivo coce declarou essa função. Para resolver o problema, crie a função nesse arquivo ou use um require iu include para incluir o arquivo que tem a função usuario_logado

Comment: Você deve importar o arquivo `seguranca.php` utilizando o método `require_once()` antes usar essa função. Sempre que você cria uma classe ou função num arquivo separado você deve importa-lo para a página que você pretende utilizar

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Então, eu não tinha feito a importação por que eu estou  incluindo o arquivo 'menu_administrador.php' em 'menu.php' e lá é que eu estou fazendo 'require' de 'seguranca.php'. Dito isso eu me dei conta de que o problema era que quando eu fazia alguma operação no banco eu estava chamando diretamente a página 'lista_alunos.php' e chamando dessa forma nenhuma das importações estavam sendo feitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta apenas adicionar o arquivo **seguranca.php** no início do arquivo **menu_administrador.php** por exemplo:

```
<?php require_once 'seguranca.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja:

```html
<?php include_once 'segurança.php';?>
<nav id="barra_navegacao"class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="menu.php"><font style="color: #337ab7"><b>Sistema X</b></font></a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><small>GERENCIAMENTO</small><span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<!--                            <li class="dropdown-header">Teste</li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>-->

                                <li><a href="menu.php?link=2"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> ALUNO</small></a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                    
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php usuario_logado();?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="sair.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> <small>SAIR</small></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Então, eu não tinha feito a importação por que eu estou incluindo o arquivo 'menu_administrador.php' em 'menu.php' e lá é que eu estou fazendo 'require' de 'seguranca.php'. Dito isso eu me dei conta de que o problema era que quando eu fazia alguma operação no banco eu estava chamando diretamente a página 'lista_alunos.php' e chamando dessa forma nenhuma das importações estavam sendo feitas.